# Linking to _files folder with htm without calling the file name

Tags: html

I am trying to link files from a `filename_files/` folder to my `filename.htm` files with html code ofc.

at the moment in the link I have to give the full file name of the folder for each file I want to link.
Is there a shorter way to link these files?

At the moment:

```
filename_files/image.png
filename_files/textfile.png
```

What I need:

```
/image.png  
/textfile.png
```

but the files still need to be in the `filename_files/` folder

**Solution:**

You can do that by specifying the `<base>` tag at the `<head>` section.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

```
<base href="//www.your-site.com/filename_files/">
```

LIMITATION: All of your relative paths in the document will now point to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by specifying the `<base>` tag at the `<head>` section.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

```
<base href="//www.your-site.com/filename_files/">
```

**LIMITATION**: All of your relative paths in the document will now point to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need configure a web-server which can give files by special routes. Or if you try work without web-server (may be locally from hard drive?) you can use symbolic links in your file system.

Comment: the problem is that it is a htm file for an email footer, this footer can only contain html code and all the files are located in the "filename"_files folder.